# Event Logging in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, event-log

I am using VS2005 C# .NET 2.0 and SQL Server 2005.

Are there any websites that provide step by step instructions to implement event logging for my web application?

**Edit:**

I will like to save the log event files as a text file in the application folder.

As my web application does login, validations and checks between several SQL databases, as well as import and export of data from SQL databases. I would like to log the events above in text files.

Comment: Are you logging them to a database? To a text file? To the event viewer? What events do you intend to log? Unhandled exceptions? All exceptions? Arbitrary data? Please give more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I routinely use [Log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) from Apache (free).

> The Apache log4net library is a tool to help the programmer output log
>   statements to a variety of output targets. log4net is a port of the
>   excellent Apache log4j™ framework to the Microsoft® .NET runtime. We
>   have kept the framework similar in spirit to the original log4j while
>   taking advantage of new features in the .NET runtime.

There is excellent documentation and it is widely used.
This [blog post](http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/) has a nice, simple walkthrough.

A big advantage of Log4Net is that it allows you to record to multiple log destinations including text files,, the event log, SQL Server and many others.

Comment: where do I store the folder at before I add the reference to my web application

Comment: RuiHao: What are you asking? The configuration info is stored in web.config and you reference the DLL in your project. See the documentation. I routinely install it with NuGet

Comment: is Log4Net compatible with VS2005?

Comment: RuiHao: Yes, it is compatible with VS2005. Here is a walkthrough using VS2003 for a website: http://haacked.com/archive/2005/03/07/ConfiguringLog4NetForWebApplications.aspx

Comment: @JohnyBoats thanks. Do I require adding a reference to my project? I do not see any DLLs in the log4Net folder I downloaded

Comment: Yes, you need to add a reference Add to the project a reference to the \bin\net\2.0\release\log4net.dll assembly in the log4net distribution. from http://sadi02.wordpress.com/2008/06/29/log4net-tutorial-in-c-net-how-can-i-show-log-in-a-file/

Comment: @JohnnyBoats I do not see any Bin folder in the downloaded zip. Am I mistaken of what you're portraying?

Comment: RUiHAO: Did you download the source or the binary? You want http://newverhost.com/pub//logging/log4net/binaries/log4net-1.2.11-bin-newkey.zip

Comment: I downloaded the source. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Look into [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/) for your logging needs. There's even a [sample application](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/example-apps.html) page.